# Send message with Malign via http request

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest, mailgun

I try to send a message via http request using Mailgun, the system give me back a 200 ok but the message never send.

here my code, (I run my code inside a parse httpReuest function) any idea?

```
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://api:MYAPIKEY@api.mailgun.net/v3/MYDOMAIN.net/message',

    params: {
      from: 'XX@XX.net',
      to: 'XX.XX@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Hello',
      text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'

    }
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    console.log('Request response ' + httpResponse.error);
  }, function(httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
  });
```

Comment: What do your Mailgun logs say? How do you know the message isn't getting sent?

I believe Mailgun requires you to validate your account, so you'll want to make sure everything is configured correctly there, too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... I make a mistake in the api call the right call is.

```
url: 'https://api:MYAPIKEY@api.mailgun.net/v3/MYDOMAIN.net/messages',
```

with messages not message

forgot and s and waste the entire day :-(